# Como instalo la extensión Python para todos los usuarios en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio, server, extensiones

trabaja sobre Windows Server 2019 y hay que instalar la extensión de Python, pero no consigo que la instale para todos los usuarios que se conecten, solo para el que la instala.
Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buenas, tengo un windows server 2019 en un colegio que utiliza Visual Studio Code.  La aplicación se instala para todos los usuarios sin problema, pero la extensión de Python para esta apliación no consigo que se instale para todos los usuarios que se conecten. Tienen que instalarla uno por uno  y no es recomendable. No encuentro como hacer una instalación global de la extensión.
Mucahs gracias.